# How to properly license a Widget as opposed to an application?

Tags: android, android-widget

I've been reading through the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html) for implementing application licensing. Seems somewhat straight forward but it looks as though the example code is tailored for a full fledged android application and not a widget.

Is there an alternate way to implement application licensing for a widget app?

Thanks.
Brian
www.jaydien.com

Comment: I am working on this exact thing.  I am checking the license when I start a configuration activity.  I am pretty sure that once the widget is on the screen you might need to check it with a service, but for my  appwidget I think that the configuration screens are used so much (and are so integral) that they will be fine there for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think the license applies to the widget. As you stated in the last line, it is a widget "app". In terms of the Market I think it's one in the same. Any licensing that applies (and doesn't infringe on another) applies to all Market Items.

EDIT:
My justification of this is that the API considers it the same thing. I'm not claiming this to be absolute, but I'm positive Widget and Application are synonymous in terms of the Market.